# How to share a valuable contact with a colleague without being cut out?

Tags: politics, sales

To make progress with a common project, I need to work with a colleague, a salesperson, by introducing her to a key stakeholder, a very valuable contact in my field.

Based on her past behaviour, I fully expect that once I make the introduction she will cut me out of future conversations, and I will have to chase her, ending up in a position of weakness.

If I don't make the introduction, the project can't proceed.
But if I make the introduction, I might lose leverage from my valuable contact.

How to share this contact without being cut out?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In general our relationship is not so bad, but the culture of her team, coming down from her manager, is to be extremely competitive and get full control of any and all projects. It happened multiple times, they are known for this.

Comment: What do you value more: this project with this colleague, or your contact?

Comment: Why do you need to intro her for the project to continue? Because she said so?

Comment: It sounds like your real problem is the problems that occur once the sales team take control of the project. If you can address those, you don't have to keep your contacts secret. Maybe that would make a better question?

Comment: Thanks Robin, can you help me understand how a better question would look like?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't see a concrete solution to this problem, because once you introduce X to Y, they no longer need you as you already know. This is like sharing some picturesque location in your town and only allowing your friends to visit it with your permission or when you're with them. This simply does not happen.